# Failed to find files to create packages matching \BuildArtifacts\_Build\BranchName.nupkg under \BuildAgent\work\randomnumbers

Tags: c#, msbuild, virtual-machine, teamcity, build-agent

I am having the worse time trying to figure out why branches have problems to build in TeamCity.
Branch A (master) is building correctly but the branch B (child) after the commit is not.

I've moved two files and made changes only in cshtml and js files, I was wondering if moving files had something to do with this errors, but after moving files to it original location nothing has changed.

Error from the title is the only thing I have, there is nothing in Build Agent log files. Branch is building correctly on my local machine and Virtual Machine that is hosting TeamCity Build Agent in Visual Studio both 2017 and 2015.

If there is anything that I need to provide please let me know.

Failed to find files to create packages matching: [C:\BuildAgent\work\18ff18d3bbcc05c3\BuildArtifacts_Build\branchname.nupkg] under C:\BuildAgent\work\18ff18d3bbcc05c3

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, nuget.exe had problem with underscore in branch name.